# Como criar parâmetros opcionais no SoapServer

Tags: php, soap

Estou utlizando a classe nativa do `PHP` para criar um servidor Soap.

**Exemplo:**

```
class Bar {

   public function getDrink($age, $money, $name) {
      if ($age >= 18 && $money == 5):
         $drink = "Heineken";
      else:
         $drink = "water";
      endif;
      if (empty($name)): // name é um parametro opcional.
         $name = "Hey ";
      endif;
      return $name . " here is your " . $drink;
   }

}

$options = array('uri' => 'http://localhost/webservice');
$server = new SoapServer(NULL, $options);
$server->setClass('Bar');
$server->handle();
```

Depois eu posso consumir todos os métodos da classe `Bar` no meu SoapClient, porém todos os parâmetros se tornam obrigatórios. como eu poderia especificar para o servidor que alguns parâmetros de determinado método serão opcionais?

Comment: O envia dos argumentos é baseado na posição, poderia definir um valor padrão para os parâmetros na assinatura do método.

Comment: @rray pelo visto este sera o meu pior problema, porque vou ter que obrigar as pessoas a digitarem algum valor nos parâmetros para não ocorrer o risco de um valor ir para outro parâmetro, porque como você disse eles pegam pela posição e não pelo nome.

Comment: Não sei se isso é um problema, você é o servidor logo define as regras de funcionamento o cliente que vai consumir precisa apenas conhecer e seguir as suas regras do contrário ele não vai atingir o objetivo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Especificando na função que eles são opcionais. Isso é feito definindo um valor padrão parao parâmetro na assinatura da função.

```
class Bar {

   public function getDrink($age, $money, $name = 'Hey') {
      if ($age >= 18 && $money == 5):
         $drink = "Heineken";
      else:
         $drink = "water";
      endif;
      return $name . " here is your " . $drink;
   }

}

$options = array('uri' => 'http://localhost/webservice');
$server = new SoapServer(NULL, $options);
$server->setClass('Bar');
$server->handle();
```